# Can access Samba shares but cannot list shares

Tags: samba, ansible

I have Samba configured with a couple of shares (still testing) and from a Windows machine I can access the shares if I write the whole path (e.g. \testserver\publicshare) but if I access \testserver\ I get a permissions error and I can't see all the shares in that samba server.

What's wrong?

This is my config file:

```
# Samba configuration -- Managed by Ansible, please don't edit manually
# vim: ft=samba
#
# Ansible managed

[global]
  # Server information
  netbios name = testserver
  workgroup = WORKGROUP
  server string = Fileserver %m

  fruit:aapl = yes

  # Logging
  logging = syslog

  # Authentication
  security = user
  passdb backend = tdbsam
  map to guest = Never
  guest account = server

  # Name resolution: make sure \\NETBIOS_NAME\ works
  wins support = yes
  local master = yes
  domain master = yes
  preferred master = yes

  # Don't load printers
  load printers = no
  printing = bsd
  printcap name = /dev/null
  disable spoolss = yes

  # Fix for CVE-2017-7494 in Samba versions from 3.5.0 and before 4.6.4
  # https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2017-7494
  nt pipe support = no


## Make home directories accessible
[homes]
  comment = Home Directories
  browseable = no
  writable = yes


## Shared directories
[publicshare]
  comment = Public share, writeable by all members of group ‘users’
  path = /home/server/samba/shares/public
  public = yes
  write list = +users
  force group = users
  browseable = yes
  create mode = 0664
  force create mode = 0664
  directory mode = 0775
  force directory mode = 0775

[TimeMachine]
  comment = Share useable as a TimeMachine backup target on MacOS
  vfs objects = fruit streams_xattr 
  fruit:time machine = yes
  path = /home/server/samba/shares/tm
  public = no
  write list = server
  force group = server
  guest ok = no
  browseable = no
  create mode = 0664
  force create mode = 0664
  directory mode = 0775
  force directory mode = 0775
```

I am actually using Ansible to deploy Samba.
Here's my yaml file:

```
---

# samba.yml

- name: Samba
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: true

  roles:
    - role: "bertvv.samba"
      tags: ["system"]
  vars:
      samba_apple_extensions: "yes"
      samba_guest_account: "server"
      samba_load_homes: true
      samba_netbios_name: "testserver"
      samba_shares:
      - name: publicshare
        comment: 'Public share, writeable by all members of group ‘users’'
        public: 'yes'
        write_list: +users
        group: users
        setype: public_content_t
        browseable: 'yes'
        path: /home/server/samba/shares/public
      - name: TimeMachine
        comment: 'Share useable as a TimeMachine backup target on MacOS'
        vfs_objects:
          - name: fruit
            options:
              - name: time machine
                value: 'yes'
          - name: streams_xattr
        path: /home/server/samba/shares/tm
        write_list: server
        owner: server
        group: server
        public: 'no'
        guest_ok: 'no'
        browseable: 'no'
      samba_map_to_guest: Never
      samba_users:
      - name: server
        password: -----
```

**Edit:** 
Found it! It is this parameter:

```
nt pipe support = no
```

Comment: Does the user as whom you are connecting have read access to the parent directories of the shares?

Comment: @NasirRiley I theory yes. The shares are in the home folder from the user "server",which is the user I log in with. There's even the home directory of the user as a share.

Comment: `testparm -s 2>/dev/null` is usally the better choice to "show" your `smb.conf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the following parameter:

```
nt pipe support = no
```

This is extracted from the Ansible samba role I am using (https://galaxy.ansible.com/bertvv/samba)

> CVE-2017-7494 A remote code execution vulnerability may affect your
>   Samba server installation. Samba versions 3.5.0 and before 4.6.4 are
>   affected. If SELinux is enabled on your system, it is NOT vulnerable.
>
> This role will check if the installed version of Samba is affected by
>   the vulnerability and apply the proposed workaround: **adding nt pipe
>   support = no** to the [global] section of the configuration. Remark that
>   **this disables share browsing by Windows clients**.
>
> You can explicitly disable the fix if necessary, by setting the role
>   variable samba_mitigate_cve_2017_7494 to false.